# How do replace %20 in a string with %2C?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(this).ready( function() {  
        $("#colleges").autocomplete({  
            source:  "<?php echo base_url('index.php/'); ?>test/lookup",
            minLength:2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var x = ui.item.value;
                x = encodeURIComponent(x);
                c = x.replace(/%20/g, "-");
                location.href = "index.php/test/college/"+c;
                return false;
            }             
        });  
    });
</script>
```

I have created autocomplete suggestion box where my string in url like

```
Akshaya%20Institute%20of%20Technology%2C%20Tumkur%20(engineering)
```

So, How can I replace `%20` and `%2C` with - symbol from string using Javascript? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You don't use jQuery.

Comment: ^ Exactly. jQuery is a tool primarily for manipulating the DOM, not strings. I edited your question to remove jQuery references. Also note that you're simply asking 'How do I replace on string with another?', to which there are literally **thousands** of answers already if you take the time to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the escape character `\` for `%20` and `%2C`,

```js
var x = 'Akshaya%20Institute%20of%20Technology%2C%20Tumkur%20(engineering)';

var c = x.replace(/\%20/g, "-").
          replace(/\%2C/g, "-");
console.log(c);
```

So, your code becomes something like this

```
select: function(event, ui) {
                var x = ui.item.value;
                x = encodeURIComponent(x);
                c = x.replace(/\%20/g, "-").
                           replace(/\%2C/g, "-");
                location.href = "index.php/test/college/"+c;
                return false;
}
```

Comment: Specifically targeting  %20 or %2C to replace is not the correct solution .. we should use decodeURIComponent

Comment: There can be several solution for a single problem so stay calm @user1428716

Comment: Are the backslashes really needed?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to replace %20 and %2C with - symbol , I tested below code . It is working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(this).ready( function() {  
    $("#colleges").autocomplete({  
        source:  "<?php echo base_url('index.php/'); ?>test/lookup",
        minLength:2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var x = ui.item.value;
            x = encodeURIComponent(x);
            c = x.replace(/%20/g, "-").replace(/%2C/g, "-");
            location.href = "index.php/test/college/"+c;
            return false;
        }             
    });  
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the javascript `decodeURI()` or `decodeURIComponent()` function.

Comment: I am using decodeURIComponent() but still not working ?

Comment: try it on console. decodeURIComponent('Akshaya%20Institute%20of%20Technology%2C%20Tumkur%20(engineering)'); the output you get is "Akshaya Institute of Technology, Tumkur (engineering)"

Comment: Read the question again. They should be replaced with dashes.

Comment: ooh i missed it :)